# Is it normal for your push notification to play sound when you didn't register 'UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The code below is the only notification types I registered in my App. Yet sound is still being played when a notification comes in. Is this a glitch and if so what should I do about it? The other thing I noticed is that in my iPhone settings the include section shows my App and underneath it has sounds. And it doesn't even have a on and off switch for sounds when you click on the App in the include section. Anyone know what is going on? I can confirm this is only happening on iOS 7.1.2 for me. My iOS6 device is working like it is suppose to.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```